# For all x there exists a y such that x+y=0

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I know this statement is true but I am having trouble actually proving it. I know that if x=5 then y=-5. How can you prove that properly.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to prove an axiom

Comment: The previous comments and answer shows us a **very** important thing in *mathematics* (and not only ...) : put on the table your *assumptions*, i.e. the *language*, you are working with, the *axioms* you are postulating (i.e. you are allowed to invoke) ... in a word : the *theory* that is the context of your *attempted* proof.

Answer (score 3):

$$x + y = 0 \iff y = -x$$ Given any $x$, we have an existent $\,y = -x.\,$ You're done!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "proof" comes from the existence of additive inverses. I am assuming that you know the fields for x and y. If the additive inverses exist then you are done, if they do not then the statement is not true!